# Arduino Uno and ESP8266MOD connection problem

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to connect my ESP8266MOD to my Arduino Uno, right now I've following wiring connections using jumper wires:

- 3V3 of ESP to 3.3 of Uno
- Gnd of ESP to Gnd of Uno
- Tx of ESP to Rx of Uno
- Rx of ESP to Tx of Uno
- Rst of ESP to RES of Uno

I made these connections by following the ChatGPT instructions.
Then I added the esp package link in my preference menu
Installed esp8266 by Community in the board manager
Chose the "Generic ESP8266 board" and from the examples esp8266 > esp8266WiFi > WifiScan
Then when I try to upload the code, it shows this error:

`A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header`

I am new in this please help!

Comment: If ESP8266MOD means a plain ESP8266 module instead of a development board with all the components and peripherals, you need more than those 5 lines to put the module into flash mode. Google "how to flash esp8266" or provide a picture of your ESP8266MOD and connecting diagram.

Comment: @hcheung, I solved this thanks to maxp, his answer helped me to search in the right direction, my board is [NodeMCU ESP8266MOD WCH CH9102X](https://s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/H9ddff4f85dbd4eb39ca45934bcf1c177A.jpg_280x280.jpg). So I installed the required drivers, then plugged it using the micro-usb to usb cable to my laptop directly and selected the NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) in the Arduino IDE and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use an ESP8266:

1. standalone
2. as a WiFi bridge for another microcontroller

Your electronic connections suggest that you are trying to do option 2 but the software is setup for option 1.

To do option 1: [follow this tutorial](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html)

The programming method depends on the ESP8266 board. Which ESP8266 board are you using? Some can be reprogrammed via WiFi but they usually are reprogrammed via USB.

For USB programming your ESP8266 must have a USB interface (USART-USB bridge).

For WiFi programming, your ESP8266 must have an appropriate bootloader installed (E.g. Node MCU)

To do option 2: [follow something like this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtazgora9xE)